# Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50001ms

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am testing AngularJS app and very new to protractor. Every time I open the browser, it gets opened and then waits for the timeout before throwing the following error on cmd.

> `Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50001ms`

I have tried increasing the timeout limit, but always get this error.
I have also tried using all of these:

```
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        browser.debugger();
        browser.waitForAngular();
```

The page loads properly and if I use Eclipse and Selenium to interact with button objects, it just works fine.

Only protractor is having Sync issues. Please Help.

Comment: could you provide some code you have?

Comment: Its just a config file to open browser which it does, and then clicking an element like element(by.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "ng-binding") and . = "Hello"]')).click();

Comment: Are you using `.get(url)` anywhere? I think you'll need to navigate to a page with an Angular app on it first.

Comment: @Droogans I am using browser.get("http://localhost:3000/"); but that is in Conf file, and not in Specs. I am able to go on one page by this, but then when I click an element and navigate to the next page, I get sync issues. I have used expect(e.isPresent()).toBeTruthy(); statements as well but the page still fails to sync and times out. But actually in gets fully loaded and I can work on it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible reasons why Protractor would time out:

1. Your web page doesn't implement Angular in an expected way (i.e. with an `ng-app` on the `body` tag). More often, the error you will get in this case is `Angular not found on page,` but a timeout isn't out of the question. Using `ignoreSynchronization` would fix this if it were the issue, so this one isn't you.
2. An HTTP request is pending or fails. Open up your dev console and check the "Network" tab when the page loads with Protractor (it may happen with Protractor and not in a manual test). If you find something failing, make sure you are issuing the request correctly. For example, if you're trying to access an HTTP endpoint through HTTPS, it's definitely possible that the request would fail and Protractor would time out.
3. Your page is polling `$timeout` or `$http` repeatedly. Protractor won't do anything until Angular has reached a "resting" state (all elements and data bindings are loaded and all requests have returned).

The official list of timeout reasons is here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md.

But if you check the Javascript console and Network requests as the page loads, you should be able to figure out what's wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this, I am in process of confirming with dev team about `$timeout` or `$http` requests.

Comment: how did you fix your problem with request on load?

Comment: @MatjažJurečič, I assume you're talking about HTTP requests. That's all pretty straightforward. If one of your HTTP requests is failing, the dev team needs to fix the request; otherwise, the app doesn't work as expected. If it's just stalling for a long time (i.e. it's a very large request) then you need to increase the timeout length in your protractor configuration file (see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js for details).

Comment: the http request is successful. the issue is that in chrome, safari tests dont execute, but in firefox they do.

Comment: That's a very strange configuration you're running, my friend. Perhaps you should post a new question with all the details.