# How to report angular pending requests on protractor timeouts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I've been working on some protractor tests lately and from time to time some of my tests randomly fail with the following error:

```
DEBUG - WebDriver session successfully started with capabilities { caps_: 
   { platform: 'LINUX',
     acceptSslCerts: true,
     javascriptEnabled: true,
     browserName: 'chrome',
     chrome: { userDataDir: '/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.czw4dR' },
     rotatable: false,
     locationContextEnabled: true,
     mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
     'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '3afc09d9-d06d-4c99-a788-d1118093c08d',
     version: '40.0.2214.111',
     takesHeapSnapshot: true,
     cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
     databaseEnabled: false,
     handlesAlerts: true,
     browserConnectionEnabled: false,
     nativeEvents: true,
     webStorageEnabled: true,
     applicationCacheEnabled: false,
     takesScreenshot: true } }
Started
token: a62e88d34991f4eef0894102e004e92032857700
.F...........................

Failures:
1) login form filled should fail on wrong credentials
  Message:
    Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
```

Looking at protractor documentation this error usually happens when there are pending `$http` requests or i'm using $timeout for something. I've tried setting a longer timeout for my tests(minutes) but it hasn't helped.  My latest idea has been to report what requests are pending so i made the following Jasmine Reporter:

```
var AngulaRequestsReporter = function(dir){

  dir = (dir || '/tmp/protractors/');

  this.requests  = function(testDescription) {
    var fname = testDescription.replace(/\s/g, '_') + '.pending_requests';
    mkdirp(dir);
    browser.executeScript(function(){
      try{
        var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
        return $http.pendingRequests;
      }catch(e){
        return [];
      }
    }).then(function(pendingRequests){
      var stream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(dir, fname));
      stream.write(util.inspect(pendingRequests, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
      stream.end();
    });
  };

  return this;
};
  // takes screenshot on each failed spec (including timeout)
AngulaRequestsReporter.prototype = {
  specDone: function(result) {
    if (result.status !== 'passed') {
      this.requests(result.description );
    }
  }
};
```

However the result is always an empty `[]`. Have you guys had this problem before and if so how did you solve it? Also, is there anything i can make to improve this reporter?

Comment: Check out ideas #1 and #2 on this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907351/timed-out-waiting-for-protractor-to-synchronize-with-the-page-after-50001ms/28969956#28969956

Comment: it's not #1, checked that some time ago, #2 is difficult to debug as test only fails on remote jenkins server, can't reproduce it locally. That's why i want to use this jasmine reporter to check the pending requests

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you solve this?

Comment: never did, i'm guessing my Django dev server was deadlocking on too many concurrent queries and that caused it, however i don't know for sure. I changed my testing env to use a gunicorn/nginx and that fixed my problem