# Use async pipe for polling Observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, rxjs

### The scenario:

I have a service that polls an URL every 2 seconds:

```
export class FooDataService {

...

  public provideFooData() {
    const interval = Observable.interval(2000).startWith(0);
    return interval
      .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.requestUrl))
      .map(fooData => fooData.json())
  }
}
```

Now I have a component where I want to show this polled data:

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fooDataService: FooDataService) {}

  public fooData$: Observable<FooData>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fooData$ = this.fooDataService.provideFooData();
  }
}
```

In the component template I would use an async pipe to retrieve and pass the value along to a sub component:

```
<foo-data-viewer [data]="fooData$ | async"></foo-data-viewer>
```

### The problem with this approach:

Implementing it like this is not testable with protractor (see my [last question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358405/how-to-implement-intervals-polling-in-angular2-to-work-with-protractor) or [this article](https://christianliebel.com/2016/11/angular-2-protractor-timeout-heres-fix/)). All code is executed within the ngZone and protractor will wait for all queued actions to be finished before continuing. But `Observable.interval()` will queue an unlimited number of actions, thus leading to a timeout in protractor.

### The common solution:

The fix I read most often is to use `runOutsideAngular` like this:

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,
              private fooDataService: FooDataService) {}

  public fooData: FooData;
  public fooDataSubscription: Subscription<FooData>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.fooDataSubscription =
        this.fooDataService.provideFooData()
            .subscribe(
               fooData => this.ngZone.run(() => this.fooData = fooData)
            );
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.fooDataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

By running the interval outside of the ngZone, protractor does not wait for the polling to finish before continuing and thus doesn't time out.

This means however:

- I cannot use the `async` pipe, I have to subscribe manually.
- I have to manage the subscription manually and clean it up myself when the component is destroyed.
- I cannot keep the pretty and clean Observable-style and the code gets much more convoluted, especially if I have multiple polling services.

### My question:

**Is there a way to keep the functional rxjs style and keep working with the async pipe (or an equivalent) while running the interval outside of the ngZone?**

I stumbled across [this github project](https://github.com/ksachdeva/rxjs-zone-operators) which looks like exactly what I want, but I couldn't get it to work.

What I need is a working example for leaving and reentering the zone like in my scenario without having to manage the subscription myself.

Comment: Someone wrote a nice Service, that seems to do the trick:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3349#issuecomment-280632861

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, switchMap, delay, map, share, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private fakeRequest$ = timer(1000).pipe(map(() => new Date().getTime()))
  private pollingData$ = interval(2000)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((index) => this.fakeRequest$),
      shareReplay(1)
    )
  constructor() { }

  public getData$() {
    return this.pollingData$;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1u2bj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)