# Protractor doesn't recognize element although it is visible

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have trouble with Protractor ignoreSynchronization.

I was not able to log in without using browser.ignoreSynchronization = true. After login ignoreSynchronization was not needed any more.

Here is the login code:

```
browser.driver.get('xxx');

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

$('#input-idCode').sendKeys(idCode);
$('#input-phoneno').sendKeys(mobileNum);
$('.mobile-id').click();

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(nextButton), 15000);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

In the next case, I am also testing Angular website, but the same solution did not work any more.
After logging in I am redirected to main page and get error message: 
**Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 60 seconds.** although the element I want to interact with is visible.

What could be the problem? I don't want to run tests with ignoreSynchronization = true.

Comment: If your error is "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize...", that is not related to elements.  Ask your devs if the app continuously polls $http or $timeout, typically used in a keepAlive service.  See [this document](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50001ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907351/timed-out-waiting-for-protractor-to-synchronize-with-the-page-after-50001ms/28969956#28969956)

The problem I had:
Your page is polling $timeout or $http repeatedly. Protractor won't do anything until Angular has reached a "resting" state (all elements and data bindings are loaded and all requests have returned).

**Using $interval instead of $timeout or $http should fix the problem**

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `get`, `sendKeys` and `click` are executed asynchronously but `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is assigned synchronously. So when the control flow executes `driver.get`, the property `ignoreSynchronization` is already set to `false`.

To overcome this issue, push the assignment in the control flow:

```
browser.driver.get('xxx');

browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});

$('#input-idCode').sendKeys(idCode);
$('#input-phoneno').sendKeys(mobileNum);
$('.mobile-id').click();

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(nextButton), 15000);

browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.
Protractor doesn't log in any more, just waits for $('#input-idCode') element.

Error message: 
    Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 60 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, #input-idCode)

Comment: Have you tried to ignore the sync before `browser.driver.get('xxx');` ?

Comment: `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.get('xxx');
    $('#username').sendKeys(username);
    $('#password').sendKeys(password);
    $('.btn-primary').click();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.left_action')), 20000);`

That doesn't work for me also...

Comment: I don't understand why Protractor doesn't find elements on this page when `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false`, this is Angular website.